# UWP - Interception of pointer events by parent control (where child is ScrollViewer)

Tags: wpf, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I'm looking for an approach to how I can intercept all events like PointerReleased by a parent.

My issue is that I can't intercept the ScrollViewer's parent PointerReleased event.

I want to put a finger (cursor) into the ScrollViewer move over for 100px with my finger and then release it; it should work as if Scrollviewer.IsHitTestVisible=false and receive all events to outerStack (scrollerviewer's parent), but scrollviewer should work as if IsHitTestVisible=true and continue to get all related events to itself (scrollviewer) and its children (scrollviewer children like innerStack).

I am getting the following log

```
innerStack_PointerPressed
scrollView_PointerPressed
outerStack_PointerPressed
CoreWindow_PointerPressed
```

But I'm expecting to see this one

```
innerStack_PointerPressed
scrollView_PointerPressed
outerStack_PointerPressed
CoreWindow_PointerPressed

outerStack_PointerReleased
CoreWindow_PointerReleased
```

There is a code example

```
<Page
    x:Class="App9.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <StackPanel x:Name="outerStack"
                Background="Red" 
                Padding="40"
                PointerPressed="outerStack_PointerPressed"
                PointerReleased="outerStack_PointerReleased">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollView"
                      Background="Blue" 
                      Padding="40"
                      PointerPressed="scrollView_PointerPressed"
                      PointerReleased="scrollView_PointerReleased"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                      VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                      HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
                      Height="500">
            <StackPanel x:Name="innerStack"
                        Background="Green" 
                        Padding="40" 
                        PointerPressed="innerStack_PointerPressed"
                        PointerReleased="innerStack_PointerReleased">
                <TextBlock Text="A" FontSize="100"/>
                <TextBlock Text="B" FontSize="100"/>
                <TextBlock Text="C" FontSize="100"/>
                <TextBlock Text="D" FontSize="100"/>
                <TextBlock Text="E" FontSize="100"/>
                <TextBlock Text="F" FontSize="100"/>
                <TextBlock Text="G" FontSize="100"/>
                <TextBlock Text="H" FontSize="100"/>
                <TextBlock Text="I" FontSize="100"/>
                <TextBlock Text="J" FontSize="100"/>
                <TextBlock Text="K" FontSize="100"/>
                <TextBlock Text="L" FontSize="100"/>
                <TextBlock Text="M" FontSize="100"/>
                <TextBlock Text="N" FontSize="100"/>
                <TextBlock Text="O" FontSize="100"/>
                <TextBlock Text="P" FontSize="100"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Q" FontSize="100"/>
                <TextBlock Text="R" FontSize="100"/>
                <TextBlock Text="S" FontSize="100"/>
                <TextBlock Text="T" FontSize="100"/>
                <TextBlock Text="U" FontSize="100"/>
                <TextBlock Text="V" FontSize="100"/>
                <TextBlock Text="W" FontSize="100"/>
                <TextBlock Text="X" FontSize="100"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Y" FontSize="100"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Z" FontSize="100"/>
            </StackPanel>

        </ScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>

using System.Diagnostics;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;

namespace App9
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPressed += CoreWindow_PointerPressed;
            Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerReleased += CoreWindow_PointerReleased;
        }

        private void CoreWindow_PointerPressed(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.PointerEventArgs args)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("CoreWindow_PointerPressed");
        }

        private void CoreWindow_PointerReleased(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.PointerEventArgs args)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("CoreWindow_PointerReleased");
        }

        private void outerStack_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("outerStack_PointerPressed");
        }

        private void outerStack_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("outerStack_PointerReleased");
        }

        private void scrollView_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("scrollView_PointerPressed");
        }

        private void scrollView_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("scrollView_PointerReleased");
        }

        private void innerStack_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("innerStack_PointerPressed");
        }

        private void innerStack_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("innerStack_PointerReleased");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to put the next property to the content view of ScrollViewer

```
ScrollViewer.Content.ManipulationMode="TranslateX,System"
```

The solution is not perfect, but it's simple.

More info https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/archive/blogs/wsdevsol/where-did-all-my-gestures-go

Answer (score 0):

> My issue is that I can't intercept the ScrollViewer's parent PointerReleased event.

Please refer to [Events and routed events overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/events-and-routed-events-overview) document, and
*Setting the Handled property to true influences the event system behavior. When Handled is true, the routing stops for most event handlers; the event doesn't continue along the route to notify other attached handlers of that particular event case.*

So you could set scrollview's  `PointerReleased` Handled as true

```
private void scrollView_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("scrollView_PointerPressed");
    e.Handled = true;
}

private void scrollView_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("scrollView_PointerReleased");
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

The link is really helpful; I was looking for the AddHandler method. But anyway, it does not help.

If a user scrolls his finger over ScrollViewer (touch mode, not a mouse), and then ScrollViewer throws a PointerCaptureLost event. And the ScrollViewer's PARENT won't know about any future events, even with the AddHandler. It's not clear, how to handle finger motion, up to the latest fact about the finger release.

Comment: Derive from above case description, you want to intercept the ScrollViewer's parent PointerReleased event, why your comments tell capture the route event from the parent, and what's your realy purpose？

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, I want to intercept the ScrollViewer's parent events. I have 2 blocks of comment, one is what I'm getting now, and the second one is what I want to get, sorry for the confusion. My main goal is to provide high-level events to my custom gesture recognizer. So, I want to be sure the ScrollViewer works as it works by default, and my custom gesture recognizer gets all events from ScrollViewer's parent to detect a full-onscreen gesture.

Comment: base on the testing, the scrollview will break point release event when scrolling within touch model that is by design. and it's not good practice to register gesture for the 
scrollview parent, it will make Interaction too complex.

Comment: we suggest you use button or other control to process global event that you mentioned above.

Comment: Yeah, I know I've read about this here https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues/4520#issuecomment-829762094

I'm not sure that I did get you mean "use button or UC", how can I replace scrollviewer with button?

How do you think ManipulationMode can help me?

Let me ask it in another way, how I can implement vertical scroll and horizontal page swipe simultaneously on UWP? (In my case, scrollviewer as big as page)